# Error: [0.056088] ipmi:dmi : Invalid offset : 0 occurred while installing ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I was installing Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop everything was nice and going smoothly but after few minutes of installing suddenly an error occurred Installation stopped.. and Ubuntu Window goes off new black window shows up where error occurred

```
Error:

[0.056088] ipmi:dmi : Invalid offset : 0
```

I don't know what happened.. I'm a newbie so have no experience. If you recognized what the problem is, then please help me out. Thank you

Comment: exactly same error occurs on my laptop but in my case it occurs at the boot time, before I can even start installation and then it stucks on loading screen for installation.

Comment: I have the same error, but everything works just fine :-/